# Two Column for portrait and three columns for landscape responsive layouts using css

Tags: html, css

I need two column layout for mobile portrait view for max width 480 pixels, for landscape view I need to display three columns. Here is my css code for two columns layout working, but I have no idea how to display three columns for landscape view. Please give an idea.

html

```
<div id="sides">
<div id="left"></div>  
<div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#sides{
margin:0;
}
#left{
float:left;
margin-left: 5%;
width:40%;
border:1px solid #000;
min-height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#right{
float:left;
margin-left: 5%;
width:40%;
border:1px solid #000;
min-height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
#left { 
width:100%;
margin: 1px;
border:1px solid #000;
min-height:100px;

}
#right { 
width:100%;
margin: 1px;
border:1px solid #000;
min-height:100px;

}
}
```

I have created demo in jsfiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/jackbroney/90kf0nn3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
        <div id="sides">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="centre"></div>
            <div id="right"></div>
        </div>


            #sides {
                margin:0;
            }
            #left {
                float:left;
                margin-left: 5%;
                width:25%;
                border:1px solid #000;
                min-height:100px;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            #right {
                float:left;
                margin-left: 5%;
                width:25%;
                border:1px solid #000;
                min-height:100px;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            #centre {
                float:left;
                margin-left: 5%;
                width:25%;
                border:1px solid #000;
                min-height:100px;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
                #left {
                    width:50%;
                    float: left;
                    margin: 1px;
                    border:1px solid #000;
                    min-height:100px;
                }
                #right {
                    width:50%;
                    margin: 1px;
                    border:1px solid #000;
                    min-height:100px;
                }
                #centre {
                    width:100%;
                    float: right;
                    margin: 1px;
                    border:1px solid #000;
                    min-height:100px;
                }
            }
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0yugy4s2/

Comment: Hi Thank You for your help. but i need two columns for portrait and three for landscape. I have solved this with your help.

Comment: Shouldn't we use (orientation: landscape) in media query for better results in different devices?